# Exit code -11 after installation of Vim auto completion plugin YouCompleteMe with MacVim (Vim version 8.1)

Tags: vim, macvim, youcompleteme, vundle

I'd like to install the auto completion plugin YouCompleteMe for Vim.

I followed the instructions of the installation guide at https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/blob/master/README.md#full-installation-guide

I chose the simpler option without semantic completion support for C-family languages.

Executing
`vim --version`
returns

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Feb 19 2019 12:07:03)
macOS version
Included patches: 1-950
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version with MacVim GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval      -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
+browse            +fullscreen        +netbeans_intg     +textprop
++builtin_terms    -gettext           +num64             +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +odbeditor         +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          +toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +transparency
+clientserver      +job               +perl              +user_commands
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +vartabs
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +virtualedit
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +visual
+comments          +libcall           -python            +visualextra
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +viminfo
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +vreplace
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +wildignore
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +wildmenu
+cursorshape       +lua               +ruby              +windows
+dialog_con_gui    +menu              +scrollbind        +writebackup
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -X11
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xfontset
+dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       +xim
-ebcdic            +mouseshape        +statusline        -xpm
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xsmp
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax            -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary        -xterm_save
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "~/.vim/gvimrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/Resources/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DFEAT_GUI_MACVIM -Wall -Wno-unknown-pragmas -pipe  -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: clang   -L. -L.  -L/usr/local/lib -o Vim -framework Cocoa -framework Carbon       -lm  -lncurses -liconv -framework AppKit  -L/usr/local/opt/lua/lib -llua5.3 -fstack-protector  -L/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl  -L/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-darwin -lpython3.7m -framework CoreFoundation  -framework Ruby
```

I added the line

`Plugin 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'`

to my .vimrc, afterwards the Vim command

`:PluginInstall`

executes without errors.

If I then start Vim the following error message is displayed:

`The ycmd server SHUT DOWN (restart with ':YcmRestartServer'). Unexpected exit code -11. Type ':YcmToggleLogs ycmd_62275_stderr_menu0zqa.log' to check the logs.`

The here mentioned log file is empty. Does anyone know what's the problem here?

I know there are a lot of other questions on StackOverflow and Github regarding very similar problems. But since I've spent the last 3 hours going through these and trying to get the plugin to work without success, I'd be happy if this won't be marked as duplicate and am very grateful for every response.

Comment: Do you use anaconda?

Comment: @phd Yes, I do. I heard that there are problems with that. Do you know of any way around that, maybe to instead use the preinstalled Python2 for YCM?

Answer (score 0):

https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#faq

> ## YCM does not work with my Anaconda Python setup
>
> Anaconda is often incompatible with the pre-built libclang used by YCM and therefore is not supported. The recommended way to solve this is to run /path/to/real/python install.py (for example /usr/bin/python install.py).
>
> If you want completion in Anaconda projects, point the interpreter_path option in your .ycm_extra_conf.py file to the path of your Anaconda Python e.g.

```
def Settings(**kwargs):
  return {
    'interpreter_path': '/path/to/anaconda/python'
  }
```

> See the [Python Semantic Completion section](https://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/#python-semantic-completion) for more details.